# C++ Classes and constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Someone wants to save me some time on how classes and constructors work in c++ ? This is what I got - it do not work. I want to the class to have an constructor that takes a filename and reads a file with that name from the filesystem.

this is the header and implementation

```
#ifndef __narcissism__Histogram__
#define __narcissism__Histogram__

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>  // for ostringstream
#include <iomanip>  // for setw, setfill
#include <ios>      // for hex stream manipulator
using namespace std;
#include "random.h" // for randomInteger
#include "strlib.h" // for integerToString
#include "error.h"  // for error



class Histogram {
public:

/** Constructor:
  * 
  *  */
Histogram(string filename)
{
    readfile(filename);

}


private:

int readfile(string filename);

};




#endif /* defined(__narcissism__Histogram__) */
```

*.cpp

```
 #include "Histogram.h"



 int readfile(string filename)
 {
 return 0;
 }
```

Error msg:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"Histogram::readfile(std::string)", referenced from:
  Histogram::Histogram(std::string) in narcissism.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Comment: In the *.cpp file you need to prefix the definition of readfile with the name of the class, i.e. `int Histogram::readfile`

Comment: Don't use double underscores. Names with double underscores are reserved.

Comment: That's a *really* bad question. How did you get the idea that a function just returning zero does anything apart from returning zero?

Comment: Jakub: editet the question with error msg

Comment: and a comment and not the answer to your question, but do not put using namespace std; into your header file.

Comment: JohnB:since I haven´t yet implemented it.

Comment: Specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574407#12574407 - "A common mistake is forgetting to qualify the name"

Comment: `int Histogram::readfile (string filename)`, as mentioned above.

Comment: Luchian Grigore is very knowledgeable in both C++ and the history of C++ questions asked on StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `Histogram::` in the definition of the member function:

```
 int Histogram::readfile(string filename)
 {
 return 0;
 }
```

Otherwise it would define a new global function with the same name, leaving the member function undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is that readfile is a member of Histogram so in the .cpp file it should be:

```
int Histogram::readfile( string filename )
{
     // implement
}
```

The function you wrote though would actually, at this point, be a valid function. (It would fail in compilation if it tried to access of any Histogram's members, which presumably a proper implementation of readfile would: the purpose is surely to set these members from data it reads from the file).

You instead got a link error because there was no implementation defined for the function called readfile that is a member of the class Histogram.